Upon loading a view, how do I set the value of a property based on the value of an @AppStorage property without triggering onChange?
I have a Toggle component in my view that I want to set the value for when the view loads (based on the value of an @AppStorage property). But I also have an onChange method listening to the Toggle property that I don't want to trigger until after the view loads. I haven't been able to get onChange to ignore that initial property set. I've tried using the onAppear with flags, as well as using onInit() and accessing UserDefaults directly (which is always empy when onInit() fires). What am I doing wrong here?
// SwiftUI View
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var oauthManager: OAuthManager
    @Environment(\.webAuthenticationSession) private var webAuthenticationSession
    @AppStorage("twitchAccessToken") var twitchAccessToken: String = ""
    @State private var activateTwitchAccount = false
    
    
//    init() {
//        print("login view initialized")
//        if let twitchToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "twitchAccessToken"), !twitchToken.isEmpty {
//            self.activateTwitchAccount = true
//        }
//    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Login ")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
            
            Text("Step 1")
                .font(.title)
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Connect Accounts")) {
                    HStack {
//                          Connect to user's Twitch account
                        Toggle("Connect Twitch", isOn: $activateTwitchAccount)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()

        .onChange(of: self.activateTwitchAccount) { oldValue, newValue in
            // if self.hasAppeared == true {
            if (newValue == true) {
                // Do things here
                
            } else {
                
            }
            // }
        }
//        .onAppear {
//            self.hasAppeared = false
//            if !self.twitchAccessToken.isEmpty {
//                self.activateTwitchAccount = true
//            } else {
//                self.activateTwitchAccount = false
//            }
//            self.hasAppeared = true
//        }
    }
}


onAppear with flags seem like a good idea. When you set the toggle’s value, also set a flag. Check for that flag in onChange and reset it. Is there anything wrong with that?

@Sweeper Take a look at my commented out onAppear. Is that what you mean or something different? The onChange still fires.

No. I mean you should check the flag in onChange.

@Sweeper Ok, I put a if self.hasAppeared == true conditional in onChange to demonstrate what I tried. Still fires because onChange waits until onAppear has completed.

have a look at this SO post/answer How to initialize a property so that the onChange does not track its change of value until properly initialized to get a different approach

Can’t you use the new onChange that takes an initial parameter or are you on an older version, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:initial:_:)-8wgw9

This is of topic, but worth to mention, since you are using the Twitch API for login: the Twitch API does not support OAuth's authorisation code flow with PKCE for public clients. This means, there's no way to securely use a web-authentication from a mobile app or a desktop app. If you keep a client secret in a public app , it is at risk. You have to use the (deprecated) implicit grant flow - which requires you to implement a login screen where the user inputs its password directly. See also: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/

@JoakimDanielson I've tried setting initial to both true and false and no difference.

@CouchDeveloper Thank you, very important info! I'm not actually keeping a secret on the client, just a client id.

You could use a computed binding or the toggle, so it can be on either when there is a token or if the user requested one, e.g.
private var toggleIsOn: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding {
        !twitchAccessToken.isEmpty || activateTwitchAccount
    } set: { newValue in
        activateTwitchAccount = newValue
        if !newValue {
            twitchAccessToken = ""
        }
    }
}

Toggle("Connect Twitch", isOn: toggleIsOn)

If getting the token fails in onChange and twitchAccessToken stays empty then set activateTwitchAccount back to false so they can try again.

I solved this by using a custom struct and binding function.
The struct:
private struct SliderStatus: Equatable {
    var value = false
    var isTriggering = false
}

The function:
private func bindingForTwitchAccount() -> Binding<Bool> {
            Binding(
                get: {
                    // Custom logic for the getter
                    self.activateTwitchAccount.value
                },
                set: {
                    // Custom logic for the setter
                    self.activateTwitchAccount = SliderStatus(value: $0, isTriggering: true)
                }
            )
        }

So now components and functions can choose whether to trigger onChange when they change state.
Example usage:
Toggle("Connect Twitch", isOn: self.bindingForTwitchAccount())

And I can set the property initially like:
.onAppear {
            if !self.twitchAccessToken.isEmpty {
                self.activateTwitchAccount = SliderStatus(value: true, isTriggering: false)
            } else {
                self.activateTwitchAccount = SliderStatus(value: false, isTriggering: false)
            }
        }

